# How do you add a new form to an existing c++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, forms, command-line-interface

I want to add a new form which loads at startup on an existing command line c++ project , how do i go about this ?

Comment: Platform?  Compiler?  "Form" seems to me to be a Microsoft-ism, so I'm guessing [visualstudio-2008] or similar would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right click on project->add->New Item->select UI under Visual c++

You have to compile your app as CLR, to use win forms. Then from your exe's startup code, instantiate this form's object and then use objDlg->ShowDialog(). Its pretty much same

And clr option may not be compatible with MTd and few others(?)

Comment: How do you get the new form to launch at startup?

Comment: You have to compile your app as CLR, to use win forms. Then from your exe's startup code, instantiate this form's object and then use objDlg->ShowDialog(). Its pretty much same.